# SQL Server connection string problems

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to have access to my project from the browser, I have put it on my server .

My database is on SQL Server 2008 R2 .

When I try to login I have always this exception :

> Invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename'

I think the problem is from my connection string but I can't fix it . I tried in many ways .

```
<connectionStrings>
  <remove name="LocalSqlServer" />
  <add name="LocalSqlServer" 
       connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DataUi;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|DataUi.mdf;User Instance=true"
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
 </connectionStrings>
```

Can someone help me ?

Thank you very much .

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqldataaccess/thread/f21c0728-935d-492a-baaf-ff2704e3683b/ perhaps this will help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `AttachDbFileName=` feature is available **ONLY** in the SQL Server **EXPRESS** edition. It is **NOT** compatible and supported on a "full" SQL Server installation.

If you have a full SQL Server, you have to attach your database to the SQL Server instance, and then reference it by its (logical) database name - **not** the physical file name:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="LocalSqlServer" 
       connectionString="server=.;database=DataUi;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
 </connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should "Database" rather than "AttachDbFileName" as it is not recommended for production servers.

Hence your connection string should be:

```
<connectionStrings>
<remove name="LocalSqlServer" />
<add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial  
Catalog=DataUi;Integrated Security=SSPI;Database=DataUi.mdf;User  
Instance=true"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: I have just put this .

     <connectionStrings>
    <remove name="LocalSqlServer" />
    <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="data source=BESPIN\SQLEXPRESS;Database=DataUi.mdf;User Instance=true"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>

And now I get this strange error :  **System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user ''.**

Comment: does your user have permissions to access the SQL Server. Also check if the user has permissions to access the database and what commands are allowed on the database.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a missing `\\` in your `AttachDBFilename` right after `|DataDirectory|`:

```
AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\\DataUi.mdf
```

Comment: I can't have access with 2 \\ .

And I got the same error with \ .

Comment: I have just put this .

     <connectionStrings>
    <remove name="LocalSqlServer" />
    <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="data source=BESPIN\SQLEXPRESS;Database=DataUi.mdf;User Instance=true"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>

And now I get this strange error :  **System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user ''.**