# Where does SQL Server 2008 keep database.mdf file?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Server connection string problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8063158/sql-server-connection-string-problems)

I am developing a project using asp.net and database is SQL Server 2008. While I am uploading the project on the server it could not connect to the database.

I am writing the following code in `web.config` file. I cannot store the `.mdf` file in the `App_data` folder.

```
<connectionStrings> 
    <add name="bcharyaConnectionString" 
         connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\bcharya.mdf;Integrated Security=True;
                           User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;User Instance=True" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this query to find the location of data files

```
SELECT name, physical_name AS current_file_location
FROM sys.master_files
```

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/02/17/sql-server-find-current-location-of-data-and-log-file-of-all-the-database/

Comment: not showing anything. 0 record(s) affected @Bull

Answer (score 1):

Full fat SQL Server does not support `AttachDbFilename` in the connection string. You need to add the database to your server instance by other means (most likely [SSMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Management_Studio)), then use a different connectionstring to connect to it.

Comment: then what is the sollution please answer. @spender

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8063158/sql-server-connection-string-problems

Comment: i can not get it please help me by providing the string.

Comment: So is the database correctly attached to SqlServer? What is its logical name? Windows or Sql Server authentication?

Comment: yes i have created the database on myhosting address name of the database is bcharya with userid and password @spender

Comment: windows server but i didn't get the logical name??

Comment: @Manish. To be clear, you cannot mount ldf/mdf files as a database via a connection string in SS2008. You need to attach the database to the sql server instance running on your server before any kind of connection string will connect to it. You can't just have it in the app_data folder. When you do this, you will need to allocate a logical name for the database. Please open a new question if this is unclear.

Comment: but where can i found the .mdf/ldf files?

Comment: please tell me the procedure how can i attach mdf/ldf file in app_data folder. how can i make .mdg or ,ldf file in ss2008 on server